# Is there a way to create transient background-color on ::selector?

Tags: javascript, css

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_selection.php):

> Only a few CSS properties can be applied to the `::selection` selector: color, background, cursor, and outline.

Is there ANY way to have the background-color transient with animation?
Here is my code which I tried but didn't work:

```css
:root {
  --color: #b8d6b7;
  --clr1: pink;
  --clr2: red;
  --clr3: orange;
  --clr4: yellow;
  --clr5: green;
  --clr6: blue;
  --clr7: indigo;
}

h1::selection {
  background: var(--color);
  animation: transitionanim 1.5s infinite;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/*
#test {
  animation: transitionanim 1.5s infinite;
}*/

@keyframes transitionanim {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--clr1);
  }
  16% {
    background-color: var(--clr2);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: var(--clr3);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--clr4);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: var(--clr5);
  }
  83% {
    background-color: var(--clr6);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--clr7);
  }
}
```

As it showed this code was possible:

```js
var i = 0;
function fu() {
  setInterval(() => {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'pink');
        break;
      case 1:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'red');
        break;
      case 2:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'orange');
        break;
      case 3:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'yellow');
        break;
      case 4:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'green');
        break;
      case 5:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'blue');
        break;
      case 6:
        i++;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'indigo');
        break;
      case 7:
        i = 0;
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'pink');
        break;
    }
  }, 1500);
```

However what I want is the background of selected text to change color transiently, not with change with each tick instantly

Comment: You're right, only a small set of CSS properties can be used with ::selection, and animation isn't one of them.
There's no CSS-only way to animate ::selection. You'd need to use JavaScript for that - detect selections as they happen, and apply classes with animations to the ::selection pseudo-element.
It would be quite tricky to do well, and fairly performance-intensive, so I'd recommend against it in most cases. Just use a static ::selection style in most cases, it'll be a lot simpler.

Comment: While you could get round this with JavaScript, please be aware of accessibility issues. In particular MDN states 'Don't override selected text styles for purely aesthetic reasons'  They explain more about this at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#:~:text=%3A%3Aselection%20-%20CSS%3A%20Cascading%20Style%20Sheets%20%7C%20MDN,as%20clicking%20and%20dragging%20the%20mouse%20across%20text%29.